# Proper use of try .. catch

Tags: error-handling

Should I be using this method of throwing errors:

```
if (isset($this->dbfields[$var])) {
    return $this->dbfields[$var];
} else {
    throw new FieldNotFoundException($var);
}
```

or this style:

```
try {
    return $this->dbfields[$var];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new FieldNotFoundException($var);
}
```

...or something else altogether?

*quick explanation of the code:* `$this->dbfields` is an array. `isset()` checks if a variable is set, in this case, whether the array element exists.

Comment: With number 2 you don't actually have to throw an exception, just print out the one you catch.

Comment: well the standard "array key does not exist" error (which isn't even an exception, now that i think about it), wouldn't make sense in the way I'm using this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second example is bad.  You're taking a lot of overhead to catch an exception when, as you demonstrate, it's just as easy to prevent the exception in the first place.  Plus you also assume you know why that exception was thrown - if there was some other exception, like say an out of memory or something, you're reporting it as a "field not found" even if it wasn't.

Keep in mind that `try`/`catch` in languages like C++ and Java are very expensive because of all the state they have to save and restore. Python, on the other hand, has very cheap exceptions and they positively encourage you to use a `try`/`except` for simple validation. But even so, catching everything and pretending it's one type of exception is still bad.

Comment: @Mark - that's why I have over 3500 XP; I'm fast on the obvious answers! :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
//First let's do the checks.
if(!isset($this->dbfields[$var]))
    throw new FieldNotFoundException($var);
//Now we're in the clear!
return $this->dbfields[$var];
```

Comment: isn't that pretty much exactly what my first example was?

Answer (score 3):

Catching "Exception" is not, most of the time, considered a good practice, out of the two you displayed, I would use option 1.

Catching all exceptions may hide a different exception and mask it as a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: You should seriously consider rewording the first sentence.  I don't believe that catching Exception is NEVER good practice.  VERY RARELY maybe, but but not NEVER.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the first one, but if dbfields[$var] throws something reasonable when you access a non-existent element, then I'd prefer just returning it without checking.

I don't particularly like changing the exception type unless I have a good reason -- also if you do, make sure to try to preserve the original exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read your explanation.

I guess your method there in #1 is going to catch any exceptions that might be thrown and simply return a bool.  I definitely don't like the catching of the generic exception most of the time, so #2 wouldn't be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

"...or something else altogether?"

Neither is very good, so something else would be appropriate.

Fix version 2 to catch the correct exception, not every possible exception.  Post that as option 3.  I'll upvote something that catches a specific exception instead of `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from language-agnostic.

Some languages won't throw errors for accessing non-existant fields, and the preferred pattern depends a lot on the implementations of the arrays, tables, objects, etc.